# How do I inherit from an Observable<T>?

Tags: rx-java2

I want to build an event broker class that inherits from `Observable<EventArgs>`. In the .NET implementation of Rx, you can simply implement `IObservable<EventArgs>`; furthermore, in .NET the `publish()` method just takes the argument that you want the subscribers to receive.

Can someone explain how this is done in Java? All I want is a class who inherently behaves as `Observable<Foo>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, there is no necessity to implement your own Observable inheritor. There is a bunch of fabrics methods to create Observable and handle it's behavior. For example:

```
Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
    @Override public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {
        emitter.onNext("New event");

        emitter.onError(new Error());

        emitter.onComplete();
    }
});
```

But, if you really need to create exactly an inheritor it is not difficult either.

```
class MarkedObservable extends Observable<String> {

    @Override protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super String> observer) {
        observer.onNext("Message");

        observer.onError(new Error());

        observer.onComplete();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use Dependency Injection to inject an `Observable<T>` generator into objects. So I do need my own separate class. Definitely. No other option.

Comment: If you have a problem to inject general Observable, there is a bunch of tricks: you can create a marker interface and extends Observable class, it is open, so no problems.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, to inherit Observable, however, I don't understand what I'm meant to do with the subscription override.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk I updated my answer. Just deal with you business logic through Observer object.

Comment: Oh ok I think I get it. Except it makes absolutely no sense to actually do any of the `onNext` stuff right inside `subscribeActual`. But I guess I can cache the `observer` and call `onNext()` when it actually makes sense.

Comment: Yes, you could save link to the observer object and call it whenever you need it. But, be aware that subscribeActual() will be called for each subscription and if you develop event broker, it will be better to use share() operator on your custom Observable.

Comment: is there a demo of how to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160135/discussion-between-oknesif-and-dmitri-nesteruk).